# Importing Into SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, sql-server-2016

I'm having problems importing using the Import wizard in SQL Server 2016. It gives me the following error. No matter what I name the Ordinal_Position field, it errors out. Has anyone come across this before?

> Column information for the source and the destination data could not be retrieved, or the data types of source columns were not mapped correctly to those available on the destination provider.
>
> Cannot load the column attributes from the schema using the current provider descriptor:
>
> The column attribute "POSITION" is not valid.
>
> Please verify the ProviderDescriptors.xml file contains the data provider descriptor that matches the schema of the used data provider.

Comment: When you're on the "Select Source Tables and Views" page you can click "Edit Mappings" to see if there are any problem areas - it should put a warning triangle next to any mappings that look like they might cause problems. Have you checked there?

Comment: @CactusCake I am getting the above error when I try to click on edit mappings